# How to get auto response for any envelop completed document sign?

Tags: docusignapi

I am using DocuSign api for my client website portal as customer documents digital process. Everything works great except one feature needed.

I am creating dynamic document (with php) and sending to customer via DocuSign api to sign (using DocuSign digital signature setup).

And i have added 'check status' button in my website to check that specific document/envelope (by forwarding envelope unique id to DocuSign api get envelope status) and updating in my database and also downloading that signed document from docUsign.

Now i need the above process to be done automatically which means when the customer signs, a callback should trigger to my website url (like some webhook i need setup) and then i will check that envelop status and update my database.

Can any one give some suggestions or code snippet where i can keep that webhook url option to get auto response from DocuSign (just like paypal IPN)

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use [DocuSign Connect](https://www.docusign.com/supportdocs/pdf/connect-guide.pdf) to do exactly what you've described. Using DocuSign Connect, you can configure DocuSign to automatically push Envelope status and documents to an endpoint you specify when the Envelope event(s) you specify occur (for example, Recipient completes/submits an Envelope, or Envelope reaches status = completed, etc.).

DocuSign has published several code samples that show how to use DocuSign Connect. For example:

- [PHP and Python webhook sample](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/recipes/webhook-status)
- [C# webhook sample](https://github.com/docusign/recipe-010-webhook-csharp)
- [Node webhook sample](https://github.com/docusign/recipe-010-webhook-node)
- [Java webhook sample](https://github.com/docusign/recipe-010-webhook-java)

These samples (and others) can be found in the [DocuSign GitHub org](https://github.com/docusign).

Comment: thank you for answering my question. I will try to implement suggested code and let you know....